# Dynamic value mapping in helm using regex and conditionals

Tags: regex, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use conditionals and regex in my helm chart to first check if value1 equals value2 and if it does, uses `regexreplaceall` to replace a column in a path `some/path/path2replace`

In my `app.yaml` file I have this

```
 livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
            {{ if eq (regexMatch "[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)" (include "service.name" .)) (regexMatch "[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)" "my-sample-home-service")}}
              path: {{ .Values.home.health.path }}/app/health
            {{ else }}
              path: {{ regexReplaceAll "[a-zA-Z-]+$" .Values.home.health.path (regexMatch "[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)" include "service.name" .) }}/app/health
            {{ end }}
```

In `values.yaml` I have

```
home: 
  health:
    path: /api/v1/home
```

`service.name` could be any of the examples below

```
my-sample-home-service
my-sample-work-service
my-sample-office-service
my-sample-leisure-service
```

So if the value in the third row in my `service.name` equals the value in the third row in the `my-sample-home-service` then it should pick the default path value in `value.yaml` file, else it should replace the third column of the path value with the value in the third column of the output from `service.name`

What I get:

I get the default value from `value.yaml` even if `service.name` isn't the same as the default

Comment: That approach feels a little fragile to me.  Do you know how `service.name` is constructed?  Can you more directly compare `.Release.Name` or something like `.Values.environment`?

Comment: the ``service.name`` is injected as a pipeline variable and I gave a sample it's format in the question. I'm trying to avoid having it in ``.Values.environment`` as it's already provided by the ``service.name`` input

Comment: You're calling a template and there's some actual code producing the value.  In a typical chart I might expect this to be derived from `.Release.Name`, at which point the number of hyphens in that name will matter and be outside your control.

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried  getting the value from`.Release.Name` but I keep having the same issue